# Why update is in the present after was?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

Sentence: The only thing I did today was update the PDF file.

Can someone explain to me why the verb to update in the present after was?

Is this kind of grammar common?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We only inflect ***one*** verb for "number" and/or "tense" in such contexts, and that's already been done with ***was***.

Note that ***update*** here is a "bare infinitive" (without the "infinitive marker" of ***to update***). Including ***to*** is an optional stylistic choice in the cited example.